# MVVM - where is the SQL connection?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

Learning MVVM and I think I have a basic sample running

Let's say update SQL direct
See this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/694908/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-using-MVVM-Pattern)

In the link:  Model (Business rule, data access, model classes)
I assume data access includes SQL

But in that link the data access is in the ViewModel
Is that correct?
Please explain
Is the model just the business entities?

```
  public class CreateEmployeeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged  
  {
    private string _id;
    private string _firstName;
    private string _address;
    public CreateEmployeeViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save, () => CanSave);           
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("ID");
        }
     }
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("FirstName");
        }
    }
    public string Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set
        {
            _address = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("Address");
        }
    }
    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }

    public bool CanSave
    {
        get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ID) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName); }
    }
    string connectionString = 
      @"Data Source=RAVINDRA\MSSQLSERVERS;Initial Catalog=CrudMethod;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    public void Save()
    {         
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users(ID,FirstName,Address)VALUES(@ID,@FirstName,@Address)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully.");
    }
```

Comment: you need to learn Entity Framework (youtube search: kudvenkat) or just make a Data Access Layer. View-model is like Business Logic Layer

Comment: @PamingkasSevada EF is not a go for the target application.  I have tables over 200 million rows and some very custom queries over 200 lines.   This was a WPF the I am reworking.  User can specify a query in sql like syntax but I abstract away the joins with new search operators that do not have LINQ equivalents or get real ugly.  Like email from john as suzie.   Then what is Model?   Does the Model  mainly just mainly just define the Entities?

Comment: i had a thesis project that involved mvvm but i used data access layer. nobody cares if you strictly followed the architecture or not, whether you still write codes in your view or not, as long as the you deliver what the customer wants.

Comment: @PamingkasSevada I kind of want to do this in generally way I plan to release as Open Source.   But I am kind of learning the MVVM is not one thing.  Please verify direct to SQL would be in ViewModel?

Comment: @PamingkasSevada Just to nit-pick, the VM is not a business logic layer (not like you would find in n-tier). The VM is for holding/presenting data for the view - the equivalent for the BLL would be the model.

Comment: @Paparazzi Go with what you originally thought - the "model" is quite loosely defined and usually involves both repository access (i.e. SQL calls, calls to a service layer that then retrieves data, calls to EF) and the data objects themselves. Once you project starts getting larger then you'll want to start separating things into formal layers, so the model is one tier in an n-tier approach.

Comment: @PamingkasSevada Thanks - so you would do it in the model.?

Comment: @slugster So later I want to create a sister ASP.NET  (MVC?) so I am want to push it up into the Model and use the same Model for both.  Is that a reasonable approach / objective?

Comment: I don't understand why is this question being downvoted. @Downvoter: be so kind and explain what you don't like!

Comment: @Paparazzi: Using EF or another ORM does seem good idea for me even when working with big data. You need very custom queries? Than make a SQL View and consume it using ORM. Do you need to query 200 mir of rows? ORM adds an overhead like compiling the query, but it does not grow with amount of data being processed. Your queries should not return too many rows anyway. And if you need to be super fast then CQRS is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Liero And more down votes.  I don't get it but debate with them never seems to do well.  View won't do it.  User get to define very advanced dynamic document search like subject is x and to includes both tom and sally.   Yes I need to 200 million rows.  Even if I don't return them all they some times just want the count.

Comment: Ok, so you write a stored procedures for few tasks like search. in worst case you use ado.net to access it, in better case orm will generate c# methods to access the procedures for you. I still dont see why to avoid orm. It is huge productivity and maintanability boost, with minimal performance effect

Comment: @Liero I clearly explained the search is dynamic.   A million stored procedures would not be enough.   An for sure could not map them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, what you have done is MVVM without a Model. I presume that you started to develop you application with UX first approach, which is perfectly valid. You have created your views, than some classes that goes into DataContext of you views in order to take advantage of all the xaml binding. Those classes just happened to be called ViewModels.

The responsibility of ViewModel is to expose data and logic in such way that is easily consumable from View. Is that what your viewmodel  is doing? Yes, more on less.

But let's think next. You will probably want also to read the created employees, and update or delete them as well. You will access them in more than just View. If you continued writing SQL Statements in your ViewModels, you would most probably end up with violation of "Don't repeat yourself" principle". For example, you would have to repeat the column names like FirstName, Address in every SQL statement. If you added validation, for example minimum length of FirstName, that you would have to reimplement the validation in multiple viewmodels. That's violation of DRY. If you extract your DataAccess logic and validation, you have a Model.

Model does not have to be entity model necessarily. The easiest to extract data access and business logic from your viewmodel would be:

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
   private const string connectionString = 
      @"Data Source=RAVINDRA\MSSQLSERVERS;Initial Catalog=CrudMethod;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

   public void CreateEmployee(string ID, string firstName, string address)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ID))
       {
           throw new ArgumentException(nameof(ID));
       }

       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
       SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
       cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users(ID,FirstName,Address)VALUES(@ID,@FirstName,@Address)";
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address);
       try
       {
           con.Open();
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       catch (SqlException ex)
       {
           throw; //use this instead throw ex, since it rewrites the callstack.
       }
       finally
       {
           con.Close();
       }
   }
}
```

However you will soon see that using EntityFramework CodeFirst will be much easier and pragmatic for you, since EntityFramework does a lot of stuff for you. But I encourage you to continue writing your own DataAccess using ADO.NET (SQL Commands). You will then have better understanding of what is EntityFramework good for. If you are interested in benefits of EntityFramework especially in MVVM apps, ask a new question and ping me in comment.

- *note: The validation is a tricky part because it is both business logic and in most cases presentation logic as well. But that's another topic.*

Comment: That is not my application.  It is a link. I am just trying to figure out where SQL is supposed to go. I Google "SQL MVVM" and after searching many that is the only I found.  Access the database in the VM seemed wrong to me so I asked here.   The real application is big and complex on the data side and needs SQL.   On the UI side there is not a lot to present.

Comment: Well, one of the goals of MVVM is to have the application logic testable. If you have data access directly in VMs then is difficult to test. MVVM is not well defined framework. Everybody has it's own understanding of what it should be. Just define your goals, like Testability, Maintanability, Design Time Data support in VS Designer, etc..

I believe that when you define responsibilities of your components, for example ViewModels and you will keep in mind SRP and DRY principles then your questions will be naturally answered :)

Comment: Anyway, Model in MVVM stands for "Data Access and Business Logic". SQL is Data Access, so the definition of models answers your question pretty straightforward.

Comment: That is what I thought but as I said after a bit of searching this is the first SQL connection I found and it was in sample VM code.

Answer (score 3):

MVVM does not specify where the SqlConnection has to be; it describes the responsibilities with regards to the UI.

In many cases an architecture will contain multiple ViewModels that need a connection to the database so to have them all connect without duplicating code it makes sense to factor the connection out to a separate class. Whether that is a full data layer, EF module or a simple single class is a matter of need and preference.